# html5-canvas tag should be a synonym of the canvas tag

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

I have really enjoyed being part of the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) community for [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) for some time now. In fact I've answered more than 10% of all [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) questions ever asked on SO.

One thing I noticed during my time is that there's some fragmentation that can really hurt people looking for answers and so I request that, at the least, a synonym be created for this tag to better organize things.

The vast majority of new questions tagged [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) are for the new HTML `<canvas>` element. Upwards of 90% of them.

Since the `<canvas>` element will far outlive the descriptor "HTML5" I strongly recommend keeping [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) as the main tag, and having [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) (a little-used tag in comparison) as a synonym.

Some have tried to edit the description of the Canvas tag to include the concept of canvas on all platforms (ie Android's Canvas and WPF's Canvas). I think this is a mistake. Tags are only useful if they are for one and only one topic. Specifically these two get moved to [android-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-canvas) and [wpf-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf-controls), respectively.

And so I recommend that the [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) tag should be a synonym of the [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) tag.

---

**Up to date stats:**

The [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) tag has over 4000 questions

664 of them are also tagged [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). Many of these are legitimate questions about HTML5 Canvas on Android. Others ought to be tagged [android-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-canvas) because they refer to the `android.graphics.Canvas` and should not "pollute" the canvas tag. I occasionally go through and sort these out.

209 of them are also tagged [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf). Probably every single one of these should be tagged [wpf-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf-controls) and not [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) because they are merely referring to the specific WPF control. If there's a way to mass reassign `wpf+canvas` to be `wpf+wpf-control` I would recommend it be done. I try to sort out any new questions that arise like this, and if there's a way to do something like a mass-edit it would be very helpful for organizing the tags.

Comment: Any and all non-HTML-canvas questions would need to be removed from the existing tag before making it a synonym would be realistic.  At first glance, there would be at least a thousand, or *one third* of all of the questions in the tag.

Comment: Canvas has 3,600 questions and 627 of them also have the tag android, however several of these relate to HTML5 Canvas on Android devices and not the native Android canvas. There are 224 in Canvas+Wpf, presumably all should be converted into Wpf-controls+Wpf. The percentage is not as high as one third, possibly around 20%, though making html5-canvas a synonym would reduce that number further, and I see no reason that they would have to be removed before making it a synonym if it only serves to aid in keeping the tag's singular purpose.

Comment: I support this suggestion. Just tried creating synonym "canvas" -> "html-canvas" but couldn't due to (incorrect) error of "Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators". "html5-canvas" is certainly not "version specific" version of "canvas".

Comment: I don't get how this **isn't** done yet. the tag wiki clearly states that [tag:canvas] is **for** HTML5 canvas. (and I quote: "Canvas is a drawing element introduced to web development with HTML5. For Android or WPF, use android-canvas or WPF-controls.").

Comment: I still have concerns on this one.  **Canvas is a generic term**, and people use generic terms in tagging all the time, because people have the average tagging skill of a boiled turnip.  We should be burninating the tag by mass-retagging everything not HTML5-related to an *unambiguous* tag with a *single* possible use and a *single* possible definition.

Comment: Since there's already `android-canvas` and `html5-canvas`, wouldn't it be better to be unambiguous and just re-tag all `canvas` tags to the appropriate `*-canvas`? Then the ambiguous `canvas` tag could be removed. Perhaps `html5-canvas` could be a synonym for `html-canvas` if `<canvas>` will out-live *html5*.

Comment: I was about to post this as a new question, so I'll ask here instead - why hasn't this been done yet? The excerpt for [tag:canvas] explicitly says **Canvas is a drawing element introduced to web development with HTML5**, but the main body text also lists Android, Windows and other uses of the tag. I'm not sure of how to resolve this.

Comment: Canvas also appears to be related to `tkinter` (I searched for [canvas+python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas+python)). I suspect for these questions, being tagged `tkinter` and `python` is sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest doing it in the opposite direction, and only because

1. unless [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) is blacklisted, it will be recreated and used for all kinds of unrelated canvas, and
2. [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) seems to dominate all other uses by a comfortable margin of allegedly 9 to 1.

So [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) should be synonymised to [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas), and then we really need to cleanup whatever's thereafter mistagged.

Comment: I agree with this. This also follows other html5 tags such as html5-audio, html5-video. It would also "force" people to discover tags for their technology such as android-canvas, java-canvas, tkinter-canvas etc.

Comment: Strongly disagree. Catch-all tags are more clutter than helpful, especially in cases like this where it can be split logically into existing tags (html5, canvas.)

Answer (score -2):

Ugh. There are ~20k questions using the tag...

I would just remove canvas of all the questions. Burn it! [html*-canvas] doesn't strike me as a good tag, like neither [div], [a], [strong], etc. would do.

The `android.graphics.Canvas` tag exist, there are still [questions with both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-canvas+canvas). WPF posts should be manually edited also. I just say, lets start!

Comment: Wait you want to remove the [canvas] and [html5-canvas] tags from all html canvas related questions? More than a simple html tag, the `canvas` element implies different APIs, unrelated to the usual DOM. That can't be burninated.

Comment: @Kaiido it doesn't matter if the tag is getting misused anyways. That invalidates any possible usage.

Comment: Ok, so we should clean-up then synonymise or change every [htlm5-canvas] related from [canvas] to [html5-canvas] before burninate only [canvas] but not all together

Comment: @Kaiido that could be a compromise, but considering there are ~10K questions, is easier/faster just to nuke everything and start from 0, the right way.

Comment: Then we should really have a discussion on what is the right way. [See my comment on other post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300003/confused-with-the-definitions-of-canvas-and-html5-canvas#comment225717_300003). Also I'm a bit concerned about the gold badge users for these tags (considering that [the most active one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1693593/k3n) left last month and that [the todays one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/411591/marke) only have a gold one in [canvas] and not in [html5-canvas]).

Comment: And does this mean that the ~9K questions, related to the html canvas won't be tagged anymore?

Comment: @Kaiido you can put the tag again if you feel like doing so, but I repeat, it would prove a daunty task either way. Is preferable that it grows organically.