# Should I use [canvas] or [html5-canvas] on new questions?

Tags: support, tags

I was reading [html5-canvas tag should be a synonym of the canvas tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253790/html5-canvas-tag-should-be-a-synonym-of-the-canvas-tag) and it seems almost everyone agrees that they should be synonyms but things are stuck. And have been, for 3 years.

In the meantime while this (hopefully) gets sorted out, what should *new* questions be tagged with? [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas), [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas), or both?

Comment: Yes, everyone agrees. With the exception of those who don't, who btw. also have good and valid arguments.

Comment: @Deduplicator I apologize, I've edited accordingly. I'm so glad you made such a valuable contribution to the content of this question.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure whether you were a bit sarcastic, but I apprectiate it. To also say something about your conundrum, I'm not sure. On the one hand, my OCD insists on only using [tag:html5-canvas], but my pragmatism suggests also using [tag:canvas] just to make sure (also) the right people will see it. The problem, as you have quite properly observed, is that everyone acknowledges that the current situation should be corrected, but nothing happens really slowly...

Comment: Is *nothing happens really slowly* going to be the new [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514), @Deduplicator ?   ;)

Comment: @rene: Looks more like a replacement for "6 to 8 years"...

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326855/request-to-merge-and-or-blacklist-canvas-tag