# Request to merge and/or blacklist [canvas] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request, blocklist-request

I as well as others would like to see the two HTML5 canvas tags being merged. The two tags in questions are:

[canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) and [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas)

I would suggest merging the former with the latter so we only end up with **[html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas)**, and for these reasons:

- [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) follows the structure of other HTML5-related tags such as [html5-audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-audio), [html5-video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-video) and [html5-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-history).
- As of now, the [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) tag is used not only for HTML5 canvas. Despite its [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/canvas/info) with references to usage with other technologies, it is used on a daily basis for other things such as Android, Java, Tkinter, WPF and others, making the tag a constant challenge to maintain.
- Removing [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) by merging it with [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) will remove this possibility (using it for anything with the name canvas in it) and "force" users to discover that there are tags for their technologies (f.ex. [android-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-canvas), [java-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-canvas), [tkinter-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter-canvas), [wpf-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf-controls) and so on).

There has been similar suggestion years back such as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253790/1693593), but I am not asking for a synonym as in the linked post (which would IMO not remove the issues mentioned above) but a ***merge*** so there is *one single tag* and not two, for HTML5 canvas related questions.

Optionally, if no automatic process can be used, I would request [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) blacklisted so a manual focused process could be started in order to clean it up.

Comment: Until canvas is cleaned up I don't feel that this should be done. You will end up with stuff that [has nothing to do with html](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38016284/792066)

Comment: There are 2555+ questions tagged android using canvas, for example (plus all the other combinations). No one will clean that up manually. Is there an automatic way, db-level, to replace posts with these combination with more proper tags? I know there will be misses when f.ex. android Q uses html5 canvas, but I would rather see a 20/80 miss than a 80/20 as of now..

Comment: I wanted a tool like that, but someone (possibly Shog) said that they wouldn't do that. [I would prefer to blacklist canvas and chip away one by one all the questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290374/792066) (or that is the only thing I feel that is feasible, right now).

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326753/should-we-burninate-canvas

Comment: Blacklist trumps over retag, since blacklisting presumes a retag/burnination.

Comment: @Braiam hmm, I am not too frequent on meta. Thanks for the edits btw.

Comment: There are quite a lot related (or near-identical) requests, hidden in [this list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=canvas+is%3Aq)

Comment: @Deduplicator quite a lot actually, and since 2012. And nothing has been done about it. Should I stay optimistic?

Comment: That would be asking for quite a lot...

Comment: Just curious: Is it meaningful to make requests like this on S.O.? Is this the right forum to raise concerns like this?

Comment: Re-added the merge nomenclature to the title since it's not obvious to all passersby and readers how the details of such processes work cc @Braiam

Answer (score 24):

There may be over [6,000 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcanvas%5D+-html+-html5+-%5Bhtml*%5D+-%5Bjs%5D+is%3Aq) using [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) outside its recommended definition. We need to fix this first, but it will be a huge job.

I will see what I can do about editing, but I'm not going to be able to do this alone. I may finally see about getting the one [Stack App](https://stackapps.com/questions/4207) that helps with this...

Let's all set our Close Vote filters to Canvas and see what trash we can take out, too. I'm encountering some things that are just garbage (but will not die naturally, since they have vague answers).

It might be beneficial to ask for [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) to be blacklisted while we do this, as [Braiam said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290374). Otherwise, there will be an influx of new questions that misuse the tag. I think a blacklist would also have the same effect, at least as a temporary solution.

For those who want to help me editing:

- [2,500 Questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcanvas%5D+%5Bandroid%5D+is%3Aq) [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)[canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas)

  - This may contain some "false positives" like [this (bad) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368445).
- [850 Questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcanvas%5D+%5Bjava%5D+is%3Aq) [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)[canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas)

  - [Only 475 Questions excluding](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcanvas%5D+%5Bjava%5D+-%5Bandroid%5D+is%3Aq) [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)
  - Of course, [some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26378706/3) have other problems. In case you didn't know, Java is not the same thing as JavaScript...
- [750 Questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcanvas%5D+%5Bwpf%5D+is%3Aq) [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf)[canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas)

  - This may merit its own tag [wpf-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf-canvas), or at least a synonym to the existing [wpf-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf-controls), which it [falls under](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/canvas/) (I think...)
- [<s>325</s> 300 Questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcanvas%5D+%5Btkinter%5D+is%3Aq) [tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter)[canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas)
- [257 Questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas%20facebook%20not%20android) [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) (but not [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android))

  - These questions should be retagged as [facebook-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-canvas)

(Obviously this doesn't add up to my total. I suspect that some questions are very much lacking in context. There's obviously other usages, too, which I may add as I find. My query may be oversensitive too.)

Comment: The numbers seems about right to me based on the frequency of "mistagging" in the various other non-html5 tags. IIRC there is also a daily limit on how many edits one can do? It would take a small army if this should be done manually..

Comment: @K3N The amount of editing you can do is only limited by your time (I edit a lot per day, and I would know if there was a limit). Of course, I don't recommend that anyone without full editing privileges try that out...

Comment: What are the more appropriate tags for android, java and tkinter? Are there any, should there be, or should it simply stay at canvas?

Comment: @Deduplicator I didn't bother to mention them as they appear in the question above. They all follow the pattern `tech-canvas`: for example `java-canvas`.

Comment: I agree with the wpf-canvas, at least as a synonym. In my experience most seem find it non-logic to use for WPF canvas questions.

Comment: @K3N I noticed you had 2 score in the wpf-controls tag. I retagged the one bountied canvas question you answered to the tag (and I also up voted you). I think you may have enough score now to suggest the synonym...

Comment: Thanks @Laurel. Yes I created a new wpf-canvas tag and was able to set it as synonym to wpf-controls (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wpf-controls/synonyms)

Comment: if you have seeded the CVQ the SOCVR can spend an event on this tag if you like.

Comment: FYI, WPF `Canvas` is a `UIElement` and a `Panel`, but not `Control` or `UserControl`. I don't understand why [wpf-controls] is referenced in [canvas] wiki (wpf section), but it is a bad substitute. And [wpf-canvas
] synonym to [wpf-controls] is incorrect

Comment: I checked [canvas] tag wiki history to find when [wpf-controls] was added. It was revision 4 and user has 0 score in wpf questions. I guess it is misunderstanding of  [wpf-controls], currently described as "WPF controls include UserControls, which are composite collections of other controls, and CustomControls, which are controls built with WPF styles and templates."

Comment: @Ash what would you suggest as tag/synonym to catch the canvas panel?

Comment: @J... would f.ex. [delphi-canvas] or [delphi-tcanvas] be usable in this context?

Comment: @J... sure, but as Braiam comments to Deduplicator: it does have an effect on dup-power, charts, favorites etc.

Comment: @K3N I'd still hardly call that the tag's fault.  If dup power is a problem then maybe we need to think about whitelisting ban-hammerable tags.  I'm sure this isn't the only instance of a transcendental puzzle piece in the coding landscape.  Imagine you get a gold badge in the `file` tag, or the `string` tag,  for example...oh, the havoc to be wrought!

Comment: @J... That sounds too much busywork for avoiding having just one more tag.

Comment: @J... Thinking about it a bit more, one would hope that we could trust gold badge holders. The real problem is that these tags fail to organize questions. That's the root of all the problems.

Comment: @Laurel Nonsense.  Think of it like a relational database - this is just a primary key that is composed of more than one column.  [`html5`+`canvas`] is distinct from [`java`+`canvas`], etc.  I'd prefer that to the tag pollution and dilution of the alternative.

Comment: @J... a primary key doesn't provide *structure* which we're after (as well as the more or less semantic element). Without some structure you won't be able to organize anything. And yes, html5-canvas is an odd duck, perhaps, but it's still a duck and the problem is very real (take it from us who are active in the tags on a daily basis).

Comment: @K3N Actually, I take it back.  I previously had no idea what html5's canvas even was, I just assumed it was some new technology.  I just looked it up, it's not - it's the same damned thing.  It's just a canvas.  Same as any other canvas.  It does the same things it does in every other language, in nearly the same way.  Given that, I really don't see a need for an `html5-canvas` tag, just use `canvas`.  The language tag makes it clear what language you're talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the first question to answer is whether it makes more sense to create a unique [canvas-xyz]-tag for every combination of [canvas] and [xyz], or we should simply fix the description and abandon the combi-tags.

- Does [canvas] in every case mean the same core concept?
  Looks like it.
- Do those combi-tags serve any other purpose than filtering on the two base-tags?
  Doesn't look like it.

I would welcome someone showing how I am wrong on either point.

Comment: Favorites and the hammer works only with a single tag. I doubt the Java community would be pleased that a canvas tag gold badge holder can close their questions when he mainly answered html5 questions.

Comment: Well, that's the case for all the other tags, and most still aren't segregated by language...

Comment: @Braiam What you're suggesting, then, is a hack.  There are deficiencies in the ban-hammer and favourite system and the proposed solution is to abuse the tag system to compensate.  Surely, on Stack Overflow, this is not the type of solution we aspire to.

Comment: @J... I cannot make sense of what you said. What has to do banning with tags? And why should we build something so contrived for an edge case that has a straightforward solution?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to extend the counterargument here.  A [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) is a thing that predates HTML5 by a rather long time.  It is [a ubiquitous component of a UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_(GUI)) in many languages.  There is nothing particularly special about HTML5's canvas - it does all of the common things

- Occupies space in a layout in a parent container
- Draw rectangles and ellipses, etc
- Draw paths
- Draw bitmaps
- Draw and measure text
- Apply tranformations
- etc.

The tag [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) is therefore ridiculous and should be burned.  The wiki for [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) should be updated to be language agnostic, just the same as, for example:

- [combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/combobox)
- [listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview)
- [button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button)
- [scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrollbar)
- [menuitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menuitem)
- etc.

Having language specific versions of all of these would be a mess and serves no purpose - that's what the language tags are there for; to provide context.

To suggest bannng [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) logically must extend to these other tags as well.  We'll need [java-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-button), [c#-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-button), [c++-mfc-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-mfc-button), [python-tkinter-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-tkinter-button), [html-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-button), and so on.  This entirely defeats the purpose of categorizable tags.  At what point does the tag become [java-button-clickevent-handler-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-button-clickevent-handler-arguments)?  Surely this makes no sense at all.

The one case I'm aware of that merits a specific tag is [wpf-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf-canvas) - this is an entirely different class that has nothing to do with rendering graphics to a surface.

---

Related :

- [What is the point of generic, language-agnostic tags about basic programming concepts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300571/327083)
- [Burninate [class]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290894/327083)
- [Do we need tags for UI elements?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316236/327083)

Comment: I tried to introduce some sanity into the tag-wiki, especially making it self-consistent in acknowledging that canvas is ubiquitous. It's rather poor still, but hopefully at least a small step forward.